# How to emulate mouse hover with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Basically, what I'm trying to do is click on a button that becomes visible when hovering another element (its parent).

I have tried to use `trigger.('mouseover')` on the parent of the hidden button, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's a code snippet from the spec:

```
 # label[for ... ] -> the parent element
 page.execute_script("$('label[for=\"department_#{department.id}\"]').trigger(\"mouseover\")")     
 # le hidden button
 find(".actions").click     
 # some <li> on a list that drops down when clicking the hidden button    
 click_on("Edit department")
```

And the error ...

```
 Failure/Error: click_on("Edit department")
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError:
 Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

I would like to know how can I make the `.actions` button visible on the page, in order to click it afterwards.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Capybara provides [`Element#hover` method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#hover-instance_method) from version 2.1:

```
find('.some_class').hover
```

This method is implemented in `Capybara::Selenium::Driver` in almost the same way as in @AlexD's answer.

Note that to use `#hover` in Selenium [it's usually better to turn native events on](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions#Native_events_versus_synthetic_events):

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile.native_events = true
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, profile: profile)
end
```

Comment: Why is this not the top answer?

Comment: OP (Original poster) got his answer a year earlier and accepted it.  Time has moved on, and this answer is now better, but OP needs to select it to move it to the top.

Comment: Confirmed that find('.some_class').hover works. Then for my case, it allowed me to click a link that was only visible on hover by placing that code afterwards. I didn't have to drop down to native events (I also like to switch between Selenium and Capybara Webkit to either see whats happening or for speed)

Answer (score 19):

Alex described the solution of such problems in his blog: check it out http://aokolish.me/blog/2012/01/22/testing-hover-events-with-capybara

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
end

page.find('#element').trigger(:mouseover)
```

Comment: How do I overcome the `Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError` error?

Comment: @Hengjie `page.execute_script('$("#element").trigger("mouseenter")')`

Comment: Make sure to scroll down to see the newer and IMHO better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16581158/199712

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to simulate "mouse hover" using Capybara + the Selenium driver:

```
module Capybara
  module Node
    class Element
      def hover
        @session.driver.browser.action.move_to(self.native).perform
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Where do you place this file?

Comment: If you have a common `spec_helper.rb` or `test_helper.rb` or something similar which is shared by all your test files, you can put it there.

Answer (score 6):

Using Capybara + Selenium it is possible to use "hover" with this command:

```
page.driver.browser.action.move_to(page.find('YourElement').native).perform
```