# Mouseover is not performed in cuucmber selenium

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have tried with the following codes but mouseover is not working.

```
page.driver.browser.action.move_to(first(".aqqin-icontoolbar.aqqin-icontoolbar-share.first").native).perform

page.driver.browser.mouse.move_to(bookmark_box.native)
```

This is working fine only with tooltip but not in li dropdown. What should I do please suggest me?

Comment: I am facing the same issue

Comment: Explained here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784118/how-to-emulate-mouse-hover-with-capybara