# mouse over and click in Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

Got stuck in capybara coding. appreciate any help on this.

I need to mouseover on source element to click on the target element link.
Not finding a way to get it. need to use this in chrome browser only.

Tried the code below

```
source=ses.find('#source-link')

ses.driver.action.move_to(source).perform

ses.find('#child-link').click
```

Comment: Is this the same as [How to emulate mouse hover with Capybara](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784118/how-to-emulate-mouse-hover-with-capybara) - ie do `source.hover`? The problem with the current code is that it is passing a Capybara element when a Selenium::WebDriver element is expected.

Comment: I tried the code specified in the link, could not use code "profile.native_events = true" with the chrome browser. This is not defined in chrome. It is defined only firefox.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is hover over `#source-link` and then click `#child-link' it should just be

```
sess.find('#source-link').hover
sess.find('#child-link').click
```

If that doesn't work for you then we need to know exactly what events are triggering the behavior you expect.

Comment: Thanks Tom! but this is working intermittently. the focus does not hold on the 'source link ' everytime. any other steps can add to have 'source link' focused ?

Comment: What error exactly do you get?  If you have animations turned on then you might need to sleep a little bit between the two actions to allow the animated appear of the #child-link to occur.